# OutofMemory Error exception with Gradle dexoption in Android Studio 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I have error of outofmemory exception in my application. I added this code of dexoptions in my build.gradle of app as below but it won't work.

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'


        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "Package name"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"

            multiDexEnabled true

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        sourceSets {
            main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/facebooka'
        }

        dexOptions {
            incremental = true;
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g" // 2g should be also OK
        }
       /* dexOptions
                {
                    incremental true
                    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
                    preDexLibraries = false
                }*/
    }

    dependencies {
        compile project(':library1')
        compile project(':facebooka')

        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'


        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.devfigas:marshmallow-permission:0.0.9'

    }
```

In Android studio version 2.1.1 this code works properly but when I tried same code in version 2.1.2

```
dexOptions {
            incremental = true;
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "2g" // 2g should be also OK
        }
```

Comment: It means you are using too much memory. You should try to cut on the number of resources that are loaded in memory. Making the heap 2G will not magically solve your problem if the device does not have that 2G at hand.

Comment: Don't add **all** the Google play services. See if that fixes the problem

Comment: Do you got an OutOfMemory in your app or on your PC while you're building the app? Dexoptions only work, if the OOM occurs during build.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line in your manifest under the application:

```
<application
     android:largeHeap="true" >
</application>
```